# Is there a reason my plotly dropdown menu doesn't update data appropriately?

Tags: r, drop-down-menu, plotly

I'm working with plotly for the first time to create an interactive chart that can plot any variable from the R `tidykids` package as a time series grouped by state. Here's my code to format the data frame object as I have it in my plotly chain.

```
kids <- readr::read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2020/2020-09-15/kids.csv')

kids_my_variables <- kids %>% pivot_wider(id_cols = c('state','year') , names_from = 'variable' , values_from = 'inf_adj') %>% mutate(fips = fips(state), total = rowSums(.[3:25], na.rm = TRUE), education_agg = PK12ed + highered + edsubs + edservs + pell + HeadStartPriv, education_pcnt = (round(education_agg / total, 2)*100) , lib_pcnt = ((lib / total)*100) , park_pcnt = (round(parkrec / total,2))*100) %>%  select(fips, state, year, education = education_pcnt, libraries = lib_pcnt, `parks & rec` = park_pcnt, total) %>% filter(year != 1997)
```

Here's my plotly chain.

```
plot_ly(kids_my_variables, x = ~year) %>%
  add_lines(y = ~education, color = ~state) %>%
  add_lines(y = ~`parks & rec`, color = ~state, visible = FALSE) %>%
  layout(
    title = "% of total child spending",
    showlegend = TRUE,
    updatemenus = list(
      list(
          buttons = list(
          list(method = "restyle",
               args = list(list(visible = list(TRUE, FALSE)),
                           list(yaxis = list(title = "Education"))),
               label = "Education"),
          
          list(method = "restyle",
               args = list(list(visible =  list(FALSE, TRUE)),
                           list(yaxis = list(title = "Parks & Rec"))),
               label = "Parks & Rec")))
    )
  )
```

When I use the dropdown menu to change my plotted data, it retains data from the original plot afterwards. The range of the y-axis for education s/b from 25-69. Parks and rec on the other hand s/ from 1-7, but the using the dropdown filter to update the plot to parks and rec give me this.

[link to image cause I'm not cool enough to embed yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mI7Lm.png)

Answer (score 1):

It's a quirk in plotly that it expects you to set `visible` to `TRUE` or `FALSE` for each level of your grouping variable (i.e. state).

Concatenating two `rep()`s (one for true, one for false) for the number of states seems to be the only workaround I can find for now.

You also need to use `method = "update"` instead of `restyle` as you're changing both data and layout (y-axis title).

This should work:

```
plot_ly(kids_my_variables, x = ~year) %>%
  add_lines(y = ~education, color = ~state) %>%
  add_lines(y = ~`parks & rec`, color = ~state, visible = FALSE) %>%
  layout(
    title = "% of total child spending",
    showlegend = TRUE,
    updatemenus = list(
      list(
        buttons = list(
          list(method = "update",
               args = list(list(visible = c(rep(TRUE, length(unique(kids_my_variables$state))), rep(FALSE, length(unique(kids_my_variables$state))))),
                           list(yaxis = list(title = "Education"))),
               label = "Education"),
          
          list(method = "update",
               args = list(list(visible =  c(rep(FALSE, length(unique(kids_my_variables$state))), rep(TRUE, length(unique(kids_my_variables$state))))),
                           list(yaxis = list(title = "Parks & Rec"))),
               label = "Parks & Rec")))
    )
  )
```